# Raise control event programmatically in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, events, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a button defined in XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="loginButton" Text="Login" Clicked="OnLoginButtonClicked" />
```

Is there a possibility to raise the `Clicked` event programmatically? Of course I could call `OnLoginButtonClicked`, but I'm interested how the `Clicked` event itself can be raised.

Comment: Most buttons usually have a button.Click() method - but I havent checked in xamarin

Comment: There is only the `Clicked` event [available](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Button/).

Comment: Its not an event, its a method

Comment: I can't call it like `loginButton.Clicked()`. But what I can see there is a `Button$IButtonController.SendClicked`. Do you know how I could invoke that?

Comment: What don't you just bind the button to a command and just execute the command ? not sure though if this would raise the "Clicked Event"

Comment: @BraveHeart: I don't use a `ViewModel` here, but I think it would be the same like calling `OnLoginButtonClicked` in my case.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why calling OnLoginButtonClicked is not acceptable?

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to call the Clicked action, you can do this trick:

```
    var b = new Button();

    b.Clicked += (x, y) =>
    {
        //Your method here
    };

    var t = b as IButtonController;

    t.SendClicked(); //This will call the action
```

It is important to note this is not the right one. 
As it was mentioned before, calling the actual method is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

You can call DoSomething by event handler or any other place in your code

```
void OnLoginButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething ();
}

private void DoSomething()
{
    //Click code here.
}
```

Comment: You are right. I could also call `OnLoginButtonClicked` directly. If I could raise the `Clicked` event directly I don't have to care which method is called. So I define the called method only once in XAML. Now I have to be sure if both calls go to the same method. It's not a problem at all, but I want to know how that can be done in case I could later need it for another control.

Answer (score 0):

1. Assing a delegate method

   ```
   testButton3.TouchUpInside += HandleTouchUpInside;
   ```
2. Add the method

   ```
   void HandleTouchUpInside (object sender, EventArgs ea)
   {
       new UIAlertView("Touch3", "TouchUpInside handled", null, "OK", null).Show();
   }
   ```

Comment: This seems to be iOS code. Currently, I'm working with Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: This code was implemented in Xamarin forms ;). This's pure C#. I'm using events beside delegates.

Comment: Yeah, but `TouchUpInside` is iOS specific, despite you posted code in C#. Xamarin.Forms also contains a shared UI and has different UI components and methods/events.